# Selecting versioned data from Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hive, modeling, nosql

We need to store different versions of xml-documents with some of attributes. Each version has a timestamp. All the documents less then 100kb. And we will be having huge amount of it. My first thought was to store it in

```
create table reports (
  id uuid,
  version timestamp,
  xml blob,
  status text,
  customer uuid,
  primary key (id, version)
) with CLUSTERING ORDER BY (version desc);
```

So we can get the last version of any report:

```
select * from reports
where id = ...
limit 1;
```

But we have requirements

1. To get last versions of all reports from the same customer.
2. To get maximum version of a report that less then some predefined date.
3. To get all maximum versions that less then some predefined date of all reports from the same customer.

The predifined date can be any date. And I have no idea how to implement it in Cassandra. May be another schema? May be some of Hive stuff? I'm new in the NoSQL world so any help would be appriciated!

p.s.: we use Cassandra 2.0.11.83

Answer (score 0):

You could create additional views of the data by having multiple tables.  In a relational database you can use a single table to do a lot of different queries, but with a key value store like Cassandra you would usually denormalize your data into multiple tables that handle the specific queries you need to do.

For example, keep another table with a key ( customer, version ).  This table would allow you to do your customer based queries and simple range queries on the version within a given customer.

You could store the same blob in this second table or you could use the second table to get the id and then do a second query to retrieve the blob from the first table.  It's a trade-off between query speed and storage.

I don't fully understand your third requirement case, but you could likely solve it by adding yet another table or using the customer table to retrieve all the rows for a customer and writing code in your client to filter out the rows you are looking for.

You could also look into using something like spark with Cassandra which would give you more powerful filtering capabilities than CQL, but setting it up adds complexity and the hardware requirements such as RAM may be higher.

Comment: The third requirement means that I need to select last version of all reports from the specified customer but with condition that this version should be less then some predefined date.It's clear that I can have a table for storing only last version of report and a table for storing all versions. It would make possible easely select only last versions for a customer. But it useless when I need to select last versions on a moment of time in past.